# Redis server reports Reading from client: Connection reset on amazon ec2 c1.medium instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, connection, redis, connection-reset

I run redis2.4.16 on ec2 medium instance, the persistent is standard ebs, and i checked the redis log , found there is some log report "Reading from client: Connection reset " occurs every few hours， all my clients and server are in the same zone:ap-northeast-1a, and the operation system is ubuntu server 12.04. The client is the jredis + spring data redis 1.0.0.M4,Anyone can figure this out or give some advice, thanks!
below is the redis info command result:

```
redis_version:2.4.16
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.5.2
process_id:3265
uptime_in_seconds:2658600
uptime_in_days:30
lru_clock:561139
used_cpu_sys:29421.34
used_cpu_user:10731.37
used_cpu_sys_children:20022.24
used_cpu_user_children:75702.79
connected_clients:44
connected_slaves:1
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
used_memory:1111572800
used_memory_human:1.04G
used_memory_rss:1133101056
used_memory_peak:1112071512
used_memory_peak_human:1.04G
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.02
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.0.0
loading:0
aof_enabled:0
changes_since_last_save:1343
bgsave_in_progress:0
last_save_time:1368760178
bgrewriteaof_in_progress:0
total_connections_received:904643
total_commands_processed:592333133
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:443393839
keyspace_misses:30383206
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:359082
vm_enabled:0
role:master
slave0:xxx,online
db0:keys=364558,expires=0
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from logs, redis tries to communicate with a client that has closed its connection.

Thats probably because some of your client are not closing the connection with redis after they are done with it.

This can eventually lead redis to run out of connections (depending on your connection limits and the amount of traffic you have)

An easy solution for this is to set a connection timeout (0 as 'no timeout' by default) in redis.conf so that redis will close opened connection after X seconds.

Note: you should include the output of redis `config get *` when asking this kind of questions ;)